# How can I add many objects in array list?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am a junior android developer and I need some help in this part of my project

I going to add a group of universities like this

[image: description here]

and in every university there are many courses and each course contains many files in it (past papers, past quizzes ….etc.) from firebase storage so how I can add the courses to every university (Name of the course, code of the course)

```
public class course {

    String courseName;
    String courseCode;

    public course(String courseName, String courseCode) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }
}
```

using recycler View? by adding Array List for every university? and how to add theses courses like 100 courses for every university.

Comment: In your modal class you can like this - String name, String courseCode, List<your object>   abc etc. Then set the constructor and getter setter as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think how u want to organize your data. For example, if you want to have those courses inside every university object you could do it like:

```
public class University{

   private String name;
   private List<Course> courses; 
    
 //getters, setters, constructor..
}
```

So then u would have a university which has their own list of courses.
And yes, i would recommend you to use recyclerview for each list (University, courses, etc)

Comment: thank you for your help , but I have another question if I want to add 100 course for example in the first university should add in the code the whole 100 object or there is another way to add the 100 courses.add(course1)  courses.add(course2)  courses.add(course3)......etc.

Comment: It depends on where you have the courses information. If you have it in a server, txt file, etc, you could read it from there using a loop and create objects easier. If you don't have the information anywhere you obviously need to hard code it. Don't forget to upVote btw and welcome to SO.

Comment: this is my first time in stack over flow I don't have enough reputation to upvote but thank you very much your answers are really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Now you can try something like below.

```java
// University Class
public class University {
 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private List<Course> courses;

 // constructors, getters, setters
}

// Course Class
public class Course {
 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private String code;

 // add your files objects here, depending on type you want. 
 // constructors, getters, setters
}

// your usage example
Course course_1_university_1 = new Course(1, "name_1", "code_1");
List<Course> courses_for_university_1 = new ArrayList<>();
courses_for_university_1.add(course_1_university_1);
University university_name_1 = new University(1, "name_1", courses_for_university_1);
List<University> universities = new ArrayList<>();
universities.add(university_name_1);
```

**NOTE: This is just a sample code and you will need to add recycler view code and update provided code as you need.**

I hope this helps you out, if not, then please provide a detailed explanation along with what you have tried so far of your doubt and I will try to help.

**EDIT 1: Regarding manual entry of `Course` in `University`**

Based on your comment, you will be using a DB for your data storing. So in that case, you can use foreign key inside `Course` table. Now when you will be fetching results from DB for populating your views, write your query to return universities with courses data filled inside for seamless list population.

If you are not using a DB, I recommend to use one and if its not possible. Then you will need to add `Course` manually.

Comment: thank you for your help , but I have another question if I want to add 100 course for example in the first university should add in the code the whole 100 object or there is another way to add the 100 courses.add(course1) courses.add(course2) courses.add(course3)......etc

Comment: @Enerccio, your point is valid but this is just for descriptive purpose only. Also it depends on scope of variables and requirements. Thanks for input!

Comment: @Abooz_2001M, yes you will have to add manually, but you can use DB type scheme here i.e. primary/foreign key concepts. You can use single or list of  `university_id` inside `Course` depending on needs. And then at runtime you can filter and add all courses to a university using `id` of `University` stored inside `Course`. This is just one of multiple ways. But for a proper a way, you need to take decision based on your requirements and current structures.